# Asp.net WebForms. Erro de tempo limite excedido no SQL Server. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sql-server-2008

Em uma aplicação ***ASP.NET WebForms*** que usa o ***SQL Server 2008*** estou criando uma tela que possui um campo de pesquisa que trabalha com requisições ***AJAX*** a um método de um ***Web Service***  ***asmx***.

Para evitar requisições em massa adicionei um *delay* no método *`keyup`* do *`input`*:

```js
$("#txtPesquisa").keyup(function () {
    delay(function () {
        directoryTreeRemake();
    }, 1000);
});

function directoryTreeRemake() {
    $("#directoryTree").fancytree("destroy");
    $("#directoryTree").fancytree({
        source: $.ajax({
            url: "/Servicos/PublicacaoServico.asmx/ObterDiretorios",
            data: {
                ...
            }
        }),
    });
}
```

Copiei essa função delay de um exemplo na web:

```js
var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

Então, após cada um (1) segundo do evento *`keyup`* é feito uma requisição ao ***webMethod***.

A aplicação em si funciona normalmente com vários usuários acessando ao mesmo tempo, porém, em meus testes dessa tela (modo *debug*), ao perceber que uma consulta foi disparada enquanto outra estava sendo feita ainda, um erro de acesso ao banco de dados é gerado:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Tempo limite expirado. O período de tempo limite foi atingido antes que fosse obtida uma conexão do pool. Isso pode ter ocorrido porque todas as conexões do pool estavam em uso e o tamanho máximo do pool foi atingido.

O erro acontece exatamente no comando `Open()`:

```cs
public void Open()
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();  // <-- onde o erro ocorre
}
```

Em meu computador estou com uma versão do ***SQL Server*** obtida pelo ***Dreamspark***, não é a ***Express***.
Já onde a aplicação está instalada é a versão ***Express***.

As requisições ao webMethod funcionan, porém apenas quando as requisições são disparadas simultaneamente, como havia dito, é que o erro ocorre.

Minha ***Connection String***:

```js
 Data Source=(local); User Id=Usuario; Password=******;
 Initial Catalog=CRM; MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Classe de conexão com os principais métodos utilizados para realizar o acesso ao banco:

```cs
public class DbConnection : IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection connection = null;

    public DbConnection() {
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
        if (connection != null)
            connection.Dispose();
        connection = null;
    }

    public void Open() {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();
    }

    public void Close() {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
    }
    ....
}
```

Todas as classes de acesso à dados desse projeto são herdadas de uma classe `CustomDAO`:

```cs
public class CustomDAO : IDisposable
{
    protected DbConnection dbConnection = null;

    public CustomDataAccess() {
        dbConnection = new DbConnection();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (dbConnection != null)
            dbConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**O que pode estar acontecendo?**

Comment: Sua classe `DbConnection` é um Singleton?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possivelmente a Pool está muito curta. Acrescente o seguinte à sua `Connection String`:

```
Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=250; Connect Timeout=3
```

Isso garante que as conexões executadas não serão fechadas antes do tempo e que você poderá abrir pelo menos 5 conexões simultâneas.

Alternativamente, você também pode fazer a mudança por código, [aumentando o `CommandTimeout` do seu `SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) pra mais do que 30 segundos.

Há ainda a opção de definir mais tempo para a execução da sua requisição, que no Web Forms é por volta de 90 segundos, [redefinindo a propriedade `ScriptTimeout` da classe `HttpServerUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HttpServerUtility.ScriptTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60).Seconds;
```

Comment: @TiagoSilva Muito provavelmente sim.

Answer (score 2):

De fato o problema era a quantidade de conexões com o ***SQL Server*** que não estavam sendo fechadas.

Em modo ***debug*** eu coloquei um ***break-point*** nos métodos *`Dispose`* das classes *`DbConnection`* e *`CustomDAO`*, e com isso verifiquei que nenhuma parada era feita nesses métodos, onde a conexão deveria ser encerrada.

As classes então não estavam sendo liberadas da memória, por algum motivo, e por isso as conexões não estavam sendo fechadas.

Resolvi fechando as conexões manualmente ao final de cada método das classes da camada de acesso à dados. Com isso os problemas não voltaram a acontecer.

Só o que me intriga é isso ter ocorrido agora, quando criei essa chamada ao ***webMethod***, e não antes enquanto a aplicação já estava em uso.

Comment: Experimente usar a `connection` assim: `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) { ... }`